# Boolean indicies of extended slice

Tags: python

I have the following `numpy` array:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
```

I can use extended slicing to select e.g. columns:

```py
>>> a[:,0::2]
array([[1, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [7, 9]])

>>> a[:,1::2]
array([[2],
       [5],
       [8]])
```

But I want to produce the following:

```py
array([[True, False, True],
       [True, False, True],
       [True, False, True]])

array([[False, True, False],
       [False, True, False],
       [False, True, False]])
```

Comment: What is the questions? What is the relationship between the original array and the boolean arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

bools = np.array([[False, False, False],
                  [False, False, False],
                  [False, False, False]])

bools[:, 0::2] = True
print(bools)
```

Output:

```
[[ True False  True]
 [ True False  True]
 [ True False  True]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with: `bools = np.full(a.shape, False); bools[:,0::2] = True`

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array([[True if y%2==0 else False for y,z in enumerate(x)] for x in bools])
np.array([[False if y%2==0 else True for y,z in enumerate(x)] for x in bools])
```

Explanation:
By using list comprehension, variable 'x' iterates through each row of a. The inner list comprehension iterates through each of this('x' from outer comprehension) list elements. It can be observed that in your output, True & False values depend on index of the elements rather than the element values. Hence by using enumerate(), we get the index of each element in 'y' & value in 'z'. And using conditions on 'y', we decide on replacing with True or False